# Phonegap/ Cordova Iframe not loading after taking release build

Tags: cordova, iframe

The Iframe is loading when i take build in debugging mode, but is not working when comes in production build, i mean taking build after giving key .

So far i have done :

- Added cordova whitelist plugin
- Given `<allow-intent href="*" />` , `<allow-navigation href="*" />` , `<access origin="*" />` in config.xml file
- Added 
  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content=" child-src *;img-src * data:; media-src * ;">` also tried with frame-src *;
- Tried cordova clean android command also

The site iam trying to load uses websocket and has ssl wildcard.

Something blocking iframe . Please help me

Comment: Also tried <allow-intent href="url" /> , <allow-navigation href="url" />

Comment: u have any solutions for this, now im facing the same issue